# How to pass multiple value to the class?

Tags: php, function, class, oop

I can pass one value to the class like this:

```
class Foo {

    public $value1;

    function __construct($var1) {
        $this->value1 = $var1;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo('value1');
print_r($foo);
```

As you know, the output will be like this:

```
Foo Object ( [value1] => value1 )
```

Now I want to know, how can I pass multiple value to the class? Actually I want this output:

```
Foo Object ( [value1] => value1, [value2] => value2, [value3] => value3 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding you, you would do it by passing more parameters to the construct like:

```
class Foo {

public $value1;
public $value2;
public $value3;

function __construct($var1, $var2, $var3) {
    $this->value1 = $var1;
    $this->value2 = $var2;
    $this->value3 = $var3;
  }
}

$foo = new Foo('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
```

Comment: Everyone got voted down for some reason. Some answers are better than others, but none of them are wrong. Perhaps the downvoter would like to explain.

Answer (score 3):

Commit **multiple values with an array**. And add an output function,  like:

```
class Foo {
    public $values = array();

    function __construct($values) {
        $this->values = $values;
    }

    function output() {
        foreach ($this->values as $key => $value) {
            echo $value . "\n";
        }
    }
}

$values = ["one", "two", "three"];
$f = new Foo($values);
$f->output();
```

Comment: Actually it is duplicate a bit, but +1

Comment: I don't see a duplicate. No one did it with an array and an output function.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the other answers will require you to rewrite your class if you change the number of parameters you're passing in. Passing in an array is a lot tidier.

Answer (score 2):

Passing multiple values can be done something like:

```
function __construct($var1, $var2, $var3) {
    $this->value1 = $var1;
    $this->value2 = $var2;
    $this->value3 = $var3;
}
```

Another option is using `array` as an argument:

```
function __construct($array_values) {
    $this->ar_values = $array_values;
}

function getValue($key)
{
    echo $this->ar_values[$key];
}


$foo = new Foo(array('value1','value2','value3'));
$foo->getValue(1);    // echoes 'value2'
```

And going even further, with unknown number of arguments to `__construct`:

```
function __construct() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    print_r($args);
    // do something with this array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass more parameters in.

```
class Foo {

public $value1;
public $value2;
public $value3;

function __construct($var1,$var2,$var3) {
    $this->value1 = $var1;
    $this->value2 = $var2;
    $this->value3 = $var3;   

}
}

$foo = new Foo('value1','value2','value3');
print_r($foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just seperate additional values with a comma, and for backwards compatibilty you can provide a default value.

```
function __construct($var1,$var2=null,$var3=null) {
    $this->value1 = $var1;
    $this->value2 = $var2;
    $this->value3 = $var3;
}
```

Called like this;

```
$foo = new Foo('value1','value2','value3');
```